# XAMPP's MySQL can not start while another mysql server is running. Please turn it off and try again

Tags: mysql, xampp, osx-snow-leopard

I am getting this error always when I try to run from XAMPP MySQL server. I took a look into Activity monitor, write into search box "mysql" and there is no MySQL runnig.

What's wrong in this case?

Comment: This is off-topic for SO. Probably belongs on serverfault.com or superuser.com

Answer (score 7):

> Go to *Applications* → *Utilities* → *Activity Monitor*. **Select «All
>   Processes»*** from the drop-down menu at the top. Search for «***sql***» in the
>   search box. When I did this, I saw **mysqld**. I selected it and clicked
>   «Stop Process». I then clicked the MySQL «Start» button in XAMPP, and
>   it started right up. Good luck!

https://getsatisfaction.com/mysql/topics/my_mac_says_another_mysql_server_is_already_running_but_where

> ***** If you're on *OS X Yosemite 10.10* you can find **«All Processes»** option in the **View** menu of the *Activity Monitor*.

Comment: Yes, the <<All Processes>> part is important.  I thought this was not working until I realized that <<active processes>> was where I was turning it off.  Thanks!!

Comment: (EDIT) Found this under View. ::How do you choose All Processes? In Yosemite I don't see this option.